# Auditing, accounting, logging, and accountability... What's the difference?

Tags: audit, logging, terminology

Let's first look at the book [Microsoft Windows Security Essentials](http://books.google.com/books?id=sIKVP4JcKE8C&pg=PA96):

> ... the three As (AAA) of security: authentication, authorization, and **accounting** 
>   ... they combine to contribute to reliable **accountability** within an organization.

I'm a bit confused here, since it seems *accountability* is different than *accounting*, and it also includes authentication and authorization! OK, let's go on.

Some other references take **auditing** to be equivalent to *accounting*, while others consider auditing as **a means of** accounting.

Finally, what is the difference between "security logs" and "security audit trail"?

Please, if you can, provide me with a reliable reference, which defines the terms.

Comment: http://www.isaca.org/Pages/Glossary.aspx A fairly authoritative reference.

Comment: @StephenBachelor: Thanks. It defines most of the terms I need. There's a caveat, however: the definitions are inclined more towards business and finance than security. For instance, "accounting" is used in terms like "cost accounting" or "yearly accounting period".

Comment: A security log would be an individual authenticated recording of activity.  The log from MYBOX might contain "John signed on to MYBOX at 17:04. John used RDP to remotely connect to PAYROLLBOX at 17:05. John ended RDP at 17:07. John signed out at 17:08."  But it doesn't log what John did while connected to PAYROLLBOX. That log is the responsibility of PAYROLLBOX.  A security audit trail would be the collection of all such logs from all affected boxes, tracking John's activities from start to finish.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'll try put these terms in their respective context, which will make them a lot easier to understand.

When a user wants to use your system, you [**authenticate**](https://www.cnss.gov/Assets/pdf/cnssi_4009.pdf) them by making sure they're who they are, using passwords; certificates; cards; PINs; etc. Then check if they have the correct [**authorization**](https://www.cnss.gov/Assets/pdf/cnssi_4009.pdf), that is, you check if they have the permissions required to access certain resources or aspects of your system.

When a user accesses a resource, you [**log**](http://csrc.nist.gov/publications/nistpubs/800-92/SP800-92.pdf) that operation along with all important metadata. Your logging operation makes sure that every action is **accounted** for. You log which user has performed the action or access the resources, using which machine, using an access level given by whom, and all other identifying information.

Later, when an independent entity (external or internal) [**audits**](http://www.ocio.gov.nl.ca/ocio/im/glossary.html#Audit) the system by making sure all the records and logs don't contain any abnormalities and all the systems are compliant, it's possible to identify (with accuracy and certainty) which entity hash performed a certain action or accessed a certain resource.

A system that provides all of that in normal situations and in incident-response cases is system that has [**accountability**](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2828).

Comment: but I think it is not possible to make system that is sure 100% which users did which actions. right?

Comment: @JohnTheRipper I believe you're correct. It's very difficult (if not impossible) to create a system that provides complete accountability. But many systems (systems that uses biometrics, for example) could provide very high degree of accountability.